# Unable to call hooks in a class - react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, speech-recognition

I'm trying to add speech recognition and a transcript of what they spoke to my website, where a user presses a button to start the mic, speaks into their mic, and the transcript of what they said is recorded and displayed on the screen.

I'm doing all this in a class component called App and here is my function to handle the speech recognition part:

```
Dictaphone = () => {
    const {
      transcript,
      listening,
      resetTranscript,
      browserSupportsSpeechRecognition
    } = useSpeechRecognition();
  
    if (!browserSupportsSpeechRecognition) {
      return <span>Browser doesn't support speech recognition.</span>;
    }
  };
```

In my `render()` part, this is what I'm returning related to the speech recognition part of my website:

```
<p>Microphone: {this.Dictaphone.listening ? 'on' : 'off'}</p>
<button onClick={this.Dictaphone.SpeechRecognition.startListening}>Start</button>
<button onClick={this.Dictaphone.SpeechRecognition.stopListening}>Stop</button>
<button onClick={this.Dictaphone.resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
<p>{this.Dictaphone.transcript}</p>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Failed to compile.

src\App.js
  Line 15:9:  React Hook "useSpeechRecognition" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, but most importantly, I don't know how to actually implement what I'm trying to implement without using the `useSpeechRecognition()` hook. Could I have some help in regards to going around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is straightforward hooks are allowed only inside function components. and since the `Dictaphone` function is not a component (it doesn't return React elements) it's considered as you're calling the hook inside the parent element which is a class component.

if you want `Dictaphone` to be a component just add `return null` at the end.

```
Dictaphone = () => {
    const {
       transcript,
       listening,
       resetTranscript,
       browserSupportsSpeechRecognition
    } = useSpeechRecognition();

    if (!browserSupportsSpeechRecognition) {
        return <span>Browser doesn't support speech recognition.</span>;
    }
    return null;
};
```

and create it at its own file **Dictaphone.jsx**.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "create it at its own file Dictaphone.jsx", do I make a new file, copy and paste the Dictaphone component into that file (do I need to add like a const in front of it or something?) and copy and paste the imports for the speech recognition module from react? If I did that correctly, I then import that jsx file in App.js by doing this: import './Dictaphone.jsx';. But then how do I actually use the Dictaphone component and the stuff inside such as the 'transcript' and 'listening', because when I render the stuff in my App.js, I'm getting errors that they're undefned

Comment: Part 2: This is an example of whats in the render() for my App.js, "Dictaphone.listening". Is that how I'm supposed to use it because I'm getting errors for everytime I did "Dictaphone.(name)", and this is the error I get: "Line 64:25:  'Dictaphone' is not defined  no-undef"

Comment: Yeah. In short, you need to create a functional component in order to use hooks. you're using the hook inside a method of a class component, (you're breaking two rules at once). For more information, you can see [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)